# Single user, multiple names

Tags: discussion, moderators

What is the policy on having more than one "account"? Maybe it is an accident, but it appears that Eero and Guero might be the same person.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20218/embedded-surfaces-and-homology-fundamental-group

Comment: I think that's what happens when people don't register...

Comment: Flag for moderator attention; we can merge the accounts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be clear, this is what happens when you don't register *and you don't keep your browser cookie*, that is:

- you switch computers
- you switch web browsers
- you switch logon users
- you explicitly clear your browser cookies in some other way.

We've had users stay unregistered cookie based users and get thousands of rep for 12+ months, believe it or not.

**In the future just flag these users' posts for moderator attention**, no need to open a whole meta topic per se.

I'll go ahead and merge these two...